# nginx tries opening logs in /var even when I direct logs elsewhere

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to run nginx as a non-privileged user--specifically, my usual login ID.  I find that I cannot start nginx successfully, since it insists on trying to open log files in `/var/log/nginx/`, even when the config file I provide tells it to store those files elsewhere.

Specifically, I invoke nginx like this:

```
$ nginx -c ~/my-nginx.conf
```

The config file mentioned in that command has this form:

```
pid /home/me/nginx/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  access_log /home/me/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /home/me/nginx/error.log;
  # many more lines omitted
}
```

None of the omitted lines contain `access_log` or `error_log` directives, nor do any of the few files that are included via the `include` directive.

nginx always dies after printing these lines:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/06/13 12:43:54 [emerg] 4473#0: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

It does create the log files mentioned in the config file with zero length before dying, however.

Why does nginx try to open these files, and how can it be prevented from doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put your error_log directive at the http level. This directive can be [made at a higher level](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log). Try copying your directive to the top of the nginx.conf file, outside the HTTP block.

Comment: I've tried that, and I get a different fatal error: `"access_log" directive is not allowed here`

Comment: Oh, never mind, it's just the access_log directive that's not allowed at the top level.  I always just kept the two directives paired up during my investigations.